# Apache Tomcat Cataline file changes not reflecting!

Tags: java, apache, jar, tomcat6, catalina

I am using  **apache-tomcat-6.0.18** on windows xp prefossional SP3.

My requirement is to show additional information ( like Organization Name) in the Tomcat Manager => Server Status => in between the **JVM** and **http-** Header. I have modified the file `"org.apache.catalina.manager.StatusTransformer::writeConnectorState<method name>"` from catalina.jar source and added simple text to it. Sample code is

```
 public static void writeConnectorState(PrintWriter writer, ObjectName tpName, String name, MBeanServer mBeanServer, Vector globalRequestProcessors, Vector requestProcessors, int mode)throws Exception{

if (mode == 0) {
  // START - Added New Code to display org name
  writer.print("<h1>");
  writer.print("XYZ Organization.");
  writer.print("</h1>");
  // END - Added New Code to display org name

  writer.print("<h1>");
  writer.print(name);
  writer.print("</h1>");

  writer.print("<p>");
  writer.print(" Max threads: ");
  writer.print(mBeanServer.getAttribute(tpName, "maxThreads"));
  writer.print(" Current thread count: ");
  writer.print(mBeanServer.getAttribute(tpName, "currentThreadCount"));
  writer.print(" Current thread busy: ");
  writer.print(mBeanServer.getAttribute(tpName, "currentThreadsBusy"));
  ...........
  ...........
  }else{
    .........
  }// end if-else }// method end
```

Again created catalina.jar with modified code. and replaced with the existing jar from `catalina_home/bin`. Restarted the tomcat but nothing coming out of it.

Even if i remove catalina.jar from `catalina_home/bin` and starts the tomcat, its working!!!!

I tried even after restarting the system but my changes are not reflecting.

Please help me out for the following queries

1. Am i modifying the wrong file?
2. How tomcat is running without catalina.jar?
3. How to reflect the changes? i.e. Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on this, but I think you should place the modified catalina.jar in `catalina_home/lib`, as I believe that's where the web-applications load their shared libraries (Tomcat Manager is just another app under `catalina_home/webapps/`).

Edit: I checked one of our servers, there's no `catalina.jar` under `catalina_home/bin`, only under `catalina_home/lib`.

Comment: Actually i didnt noticed the path while posting, It is `catalina_home/lib` not `catalina_home/bin`.